# Proper way of creating a property path for a dynamically created Binding object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've created attached dependency properties on a static type (`DataField`). Among them there's an `Owner` property and `Name` property. These can be attached to any `DependencyObject` instance.

On some controls such as `TextBox` I want additional behavior for these attached properties, so I overrided the metadata from another static type:

```
static void OverrideDataFieldMetaData()
{
    //...
    DataField.NameProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFieldNameChanged)));
    //...
}
```

In the `OnFieldNameChanged` method I want to dynamically create a `Binding` object and set it on the control's `Text` property:

```
//...

private static void OnFieldNameChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnFieldNameChanged((TextBox)o, (string)e.OldValue, (string)e.NewValue);
}

private static void OnFieldNameChanged(TextBox tb, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(tb, TextBox.TextProperty);
    else
    {
        // PROBLEM HERE!
        var binding = new Binding("(fc:DataField.Owner)." + newValue);

        binding.Source = tb;

        tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. How am I supposed to create this Binding object with the proper path scheme?

Right now the code above throws a `TypeNameParserException`. I think I get why it does, but even if it didn't, what if for some reason I had defined a different prefix for the namespace in the containing `Window` / `UserControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Path = new PropertyPath("(0)", DataField.OwnerProperty);
```

In code behind you don't need a namespace definition, as you have the **direct** reference for your property.

Source: https://srndolha.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/wpf-binding-to-a-custom-attached-property-in-code/

Comment: You shouldn't have to reset the binding. That's the whole point of binding :p

Comment: So `DataField.Owner` in my case would be `DataField.OwnerProperty`, as `PropertyPath` will accept an actual `DependencyProperty` instance and not the owner instance itself. Am I correct?

Comment: @Crono: Yes, I've fixed the typo.

Comment: If the property is Dependency Property (and not CLR Property) we can directly reference that property without needing to use placeholder like `"(0)"`! it should be like: `b.Path = new PropertyPath(DataField.OwnerProperty);` But if it is an CLR property like `Friend.FirstName` then we should use it like `b.Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Friend.FirstName));`.
Another example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36506240/6296708)