# Programmatically binding an attached property in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, attached-properties

I'm using [Jason Kemp's cool `CueBanner` class](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-4-cue-banner-in-wpf-i-mean-watermark-in-wpf/) for "watermarking" text boxes in WPF:

```
<TextBox 
    hpext:CueBanner.Content="Find Text"
    hpext:CueBanner.Padding="2,6,0,0"
    />
```

[image: Don't tell Ayn Rand]

Jason's code creates a `ContentPresenter` programmatically, sets its content to the `CueBanner.Content`, adds the `ContentPresenter` to an `Adorner` subclass, and displays it when appropriate.

His code infers the `ContentPresenter` from padding and margin of the adorned control, but I added `hpext:CueBanner.Padding` instead so I could set it explicitly to a value I like better.

```
contentPresenter.Margin = CueBanner.GetPadding(adornedElement);
```

So far so good.

Here's the trouble: It works but I'd like to bind it instead.

```
var binding = new Binding("hpext:CueBanner.Padding") { Source = adornedElement };

BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.MarginProperty, binding);
```

**But what do I use for a path for the source property?** `"hpext:CueBanner.Padding"` doesn't work and it shouldn't work; that namespace doesn't exist there. No joy with `"CueBanner.Padding"` and `"(CueBanner.Padding)"`. `"MyProject.Extensions.CueBanner.Padding"` doesn't work either and I can't see why it ought to.

I can't see anything that looks helpful in [`PropertyPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms742451(v=vs.100)), but when I read that my mind starts to go a little blank.

I should be just doing this in XAML, shouldn't I?

Comment: How about `new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath(CueBanner.PaddingProperty), ...}`?

Comment: @Clemens Bingo! Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may directly create a PropertyPath from the attached property like this:

```
var binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(CueBanner.PaddingProperty), // here
    Source = adornedElement
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is that the source of the binding should be the `TextBox`, not the `adornedElement`. Based on [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/15/binding-to-an-attached-property.aspx) (which shows how to bind to `Grid.Row` via code), the binding should be created like this:

```
var binding = new Binding("(CueBanner.Padding)") { Source = textbox };

BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, MyProject.Extensions.CueBanner.PaddingProperty, binding);
```

(Replace `MyProject.Extensions.CueBanner.PaddingProperty` with the actual `AttachedProperty` you registered.)

Comment: Hi Andy -- `adornedElement` is the textbox. `CueBanner.GetPadding(adornedElement)` returns the desired padding value I gave to the attached property in the XAML.